# Not able to display text from resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, string, properties, resources

I have created very simple WPF application to test, how to obtain string from Resources.Designer.cs and work with it in code-behind.
In this file (Res.Designer) there is a property to provide mentioned string:

```
internal static string MyText {
    get {
        return ResourceManager.GetString("MyText", resourceCulture);
    }
}
```

In code-behind I am trying to modify TextBlock with string:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    tbShow.Text = Properties.Resources.MyText;
}
```

The whole application was compiled properly, however when I launch it and click eligible button, textblock stays still unchanged. Where can I make a mistake? 
According to debugger the construction `Properties.Resources.MyText` returns empty string...

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Have you considered a resource dictionary? You would need to add a reference ( xmlns) to mscorlib. You can then define strings with an x:key. Merge that resource dictionary in app.xaml and you can then use it as a static or dynamicresource or reference using application.current.resources["yourkey"]

Comment: It looks like you didn't specify a value for the key _MyText_. The simplest way to do so is to open the resource desiner by clicking on the e.g., _Resources.resx_ file. It will show a table where you can enter the key and the value like _MyText_ - _This is the text_.

Comment: Finally, I have solved my issue with resource dictionary as Andy mentioned. For this purpose I have created a new ResourceDictionary xaml file and in code-behind there is instance of ResourceDictionary class to get chosen value. It works correctly... :-)